# Do P/N matter for Diff Pair Clock Inputs to FPGA?

Tags: pcb-design, fpga, transceiver

I have noticed on a schematic for an FMC card that the differential pairs of a differential LVDS oscillator do not match the corresponding FPGA transceiver reference clock pins. I.e. the P/N are switched from differential LVDS oscillator to the FPGA. The FMC standard is supported by both Altera and Xilinx development cards, so this question is not specific to any vendor or family.

Is this a normal thing that is allowed? Could you explain how the FPGA transceiver refclk would lock to the clock input if the differential pairs are not correct?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Do you have a specific FPGA family and transceiver type in mind?

Comment: Hello @nanofarad, the schematic I'm referring to is a FMC card, so this question is regardless of FPGA vendor/family. I'm personally interested in Zynq MPSoC GTH transceivers. In their documentation they state the impedance and AC coupling of reference clocks, but they do not mention switching of polarity from LVDS generated diff pair clock inputs.

Comment: Got it, I suggest editing that into the question so it's all in one place (comments are ephemeral and sometimes cleaned up). I'm honestly here because the question is interesting to me but I sadly don't have an answer myself.

Comment: Just define the startup time of that oscillator as half a cycle longer than originally intended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is perfectly allowed. LVDS is a fully symmetric signal - If you swap the two lines, the only thing that happens is that you read a '0' for a '1' and vice versa. That's because LVDS is defined as a 4 mA current signal flowing in either one or the other direction, depending on the state of the pin.

So, what happens is that the FPGA see the clock inverted. But as a clock signal is symmetric, there won't be a difference.

The only case this doesn't work is when the same clock signal is also fed to another chip and the two chips are required to work synchronized - they would be off by half a clock cycle.

As to the question why this was done on your board: Very likely it simplified the routing by not having to swap the order of the two wires.